# ASP.NET TreeView control trouble with allocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I need some help from you:

I develop some ASP.NET Web Form Application(.NET 4.5). There I have in my aspx file a treeview control declared.

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="treeview" runat="server" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" ShowLines="True" OnTreeNodePopulate="treeview_TreeNodePopulate">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Demos" PopulateOnDemand="true"></asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
  </asp:TreeView>
```

and in the codebehind file I have this code.

```
protected void treeview_TreeNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
     treeview = Logic.ObjectsTreeView("FILENAME"); 
}
```

The return value of the method Logic.ObjectsTreeView return an TreeView object, this has the values which i needed, but I don't get them on screen.

So, how could I tell the treeview object to take the values of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If function `ObjectsTreeView` populates a TreeView you need to send the the control to the function rather than creating a new and returning it. Also this should not be done in the `TreeNodePopulate` event in that case but in Page load.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Logic.ObjectsTreeView("FILENAME", treeview);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Magnus, I have this done, but so: treeview = Logic.ObjectsTreeView("FILENAME"); but this is not working, why you make an extra parameter in the method

Comment: You cant assign the treeview control a value like that, you need to send in the control to the function to be populated.

Comment: MAGNUS you are right, now I see the structure, but the picture are not shown.
Do you have some idea, why this is so?

Comment: I get following JS error:0x800a1391 - Laufzeitfehler in Microsoft JScript: "WebForm_InitCallback" ist undefiniert; the picture I use is this standard ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"

Comment: Sorry cant help you with that.